# Factorizing exponential equation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, factoring

I have this equation:

$$2^{2x}−3⋅2^x−10=0$$

Could someone explain how you factorise it to be:
$$(2^x+2)(2^x−5)$$

Comment: Probably you need $2^{2x}-3\cdot 2^x -10=(2^x+2)(2^x-5)$ rather than $2^{2x}−3⋅2x−10=(2x+2)(2x-5)$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Or, $(2x)^2 -3\cdot2x - 10 = (2x+2)(2x-5)$. Something is definitely wrong in any case.

Comment: I have now changed it

Comment: In the factors, the $2x$ should be $2^x$ (probably a typo)

Comment: Yes i have fixed it now, sorry

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can you factorize $y^2 - 3y - 10 = 0$ into $(y + 2)(y - 5) = 0$?

If so, then substitute $y = 2^x$.

Answer (score 3):

Do you know how to factorise $t^2 - 3t - 10$ ?

You need to find its roots. You can do so by applying the standard formula *or* checking the divisors of $10$ (that is, $\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 5, \pm 10$)

Once you have factored that, set $t = 2^x$ to get the result you want

Answer (score 1):

$$2^{2x}−3⋅2^x−10=0$$

$$2^{2x}−5⋅2^x+2\cdot2^x−10=0$$

$$2^x(2^{x}−5)+2(2^x−5)=0$$

$$(2^x+2)(2^{x}−5)=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Use : $2^x=y$ so that the equation become:
$$
y^2-3y -10=0
$$
that you can easely factorize.

Answer (score 0):

you can also solve it without substituting $y=2x$

$2^{2x}−3⋅2^x−10=0$

Now, break $3⋅2^x$ into $−5⋅26x+2⋅2^x$

$2^{2x}−5⋅2^x+2⋅2^x−10=0$

Take $2^x$ common out from first two terms and $2$ from last two terms.

$2^x(2^x−5)+2(2^x−5)=0$

$(2^x+2)(2^x−5)=0$